# kendo grid can't show number record

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

""" Kendo UI Grid """

My grid can't show number record and total page and next page

grid footer show "No items to display"

prev and next  symbol << < 0 > >>

I put pageable or pagesize but why don't show T_T

Please help me !!!

```
                    var dataSourceUser = new kendo.data.DataSource({            
                        transport: {
                            read: "adminUser.php?action=view",
                            destroy: {
                                url: function (options) {
                                $.ajax(
                                    {
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: 'adminUser.php?action=delete',
                                        data: { 
                                                    UserID: options.UserID
                                        },
                                        complete: function(e) {
                                              $("#gridUser").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); 
                                         }                                          
                                    });
                                return;
                                },
                                dataType : "json"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: function (options) {
                                $.ajax(
                                    {
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: 'adminUser.php?action=create',
                                        data: { 
                                                    Username: options.Username,  
                                                    Password: options.Password, 
                                                    PCUID: options.PCUID,  
                                                    adp_id: options.adp_id
                                        },
                                        complete: function(e) {
                                              $("#gridUser").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); 
                                         }                                          
                                    });
                                return;
                                },
                                dataType : "json"
                            },
                            update: {
                                url: function (options) {
                                $.ajax(
                                    {
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: 'adminUser.php?action=update',
                                        data: { 
                                                    UserID: options.UserID,
                                                    Username: options.Username,  
                                                    Password: options.Password, 
                                                    PCUID: options.PCUID,  
                                                    adp_id: options.adp_id
                                        },
                                        complete: function(e) {
                                              $("#gridUser").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); 
                                         }                                          
                                    });
                                return;
                                },
                                dataType : "json"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read") {
                                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                              } 
                              return options;
                            } 
                        },
                        batch: false,
                        pageSize: 15,
                        schema: {
                            data: "data",
                            model: {
                                id: "UserID",
                                fields: {
                                    UserID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    Username: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    Password: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    PCUID: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    adp_id: { validation: { required: true } }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                $("#gridUser").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSourceUser,
                    pageable: true,
                    toolbar: ["create"],
                    pageable: true,
                    columns: [
                        { field:"UserID", title: "UserID", width: "100px" },
                        { field:"Username", title: "Username", width: "100px" },
                        { field:"Password", title: "Password", width: "200px" },
                        { field:"PCUID", title: "PCUID", width: "100px" },
                        { field:"adp_id", title: "adp_id", width: "200px" },
                        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "160px" }],
                    editable: "popup"
                });
```

adminUser.php

```
{"data":[{"UserID":"1","Username":"test1","Password":"1234","PCUID":"001","adp_id":"1"},{"UserID":"2","Username":"test2","Password":"1234","PCUID":"002","adp_id":"2"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this you need to look at the network traffic. In Chrome just press F12 and go to the Network tab.

Once there (different depending on browser) you should see your request to "adminUser.php?action=view", hopefully the result is JSON with the data requested.

Based on your settings it is expecting:

```
{
    data: [
        { UserID: 123, Username: 'abc', Password: 'abc', PCUID: 123, adp_ip: 123 },
        { UserID: 456, Username: 'abc', Password: 'abc', PCUID: 123, adp_ip: 123 }
    ]
}
```

Comment: {"data":[{"UserID":"1","Username":"homc","Password":"1234","PCUID":"001","adp_id":"1"},{"UserID":"2","Username":"mysql","Password":"1234","PCUID":"002","adp_id":"2"}]}

Comment: If you replace your dataSourceUser content to just have `data: [{"UserID":"1","Username":"homc","Password":"1234","PCUID":"001","adp_id‌​":"1"}, "UserID":"2","Username":"mysql","Password":"1234","PCUID":"002","adp_id":‌​"2"}], pageSize: 15` and see if that works, it did in my tests. That would suggest that your data isn't coming back in a way the DataSource understands, perhaps you need to force "json" as the read.dataType?